# Ansible when conditional is not skipping condition when false and giving error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Here is my ansible tasks within a role

```
- name: include tcrj01 variables from prefix_lists
  include_vars:
    file: "../collection-data/output/{{ market_input | lower }}tcrj01_prefix_lists.yml"
    name: prefix01
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: '"target1" in market_input or "target2" in market_input'

- name: include dsrj01 variables from prefix_lists
  include_vars:
    file: "../collection-data/output/{{ market_input | lower }}dsrj01_prefix_lists.yml"
    name: prefix01
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: '"target1" not in market_input or "target2" not in market_input'
```

market_input == "target1"

The error I'm getting is `"Could not find or access '../collection-data/output/targetdsrj01_prefix_lists.yml'`which is correct because that file does not and should not exist because the `target` string IS in/equal to the `market_input` variable. It should be looking for a tcrj file which does exist for that target string and not the dsrj file it is throwing the error about. I can not figure out why the dsrj task is not being skipped. It works for other target strings that but not the one I am currently running. I will provide more details or clarity if needd. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the *text in string* comparison, and exact match is sufficient -- a  better way to write the `when` conditions would be to actually match string item in list, i.e. `market_input in ["target1", "target2"]`.

Going with this structure, the tasks would look like this:

```yaml
- name: include tcrj01 variables from prefix_lists
  include_vars:
    file: "../collection-data/output/{{ market_input | lower }}tcrj01_prefix_lists.yml"
    name: prefix01
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: market_input | lower in ["target1", "target2"]

- name: include dsrj01 variables from prefix_lists
  include_vars:
    file: "../collection-data/output/{{ market_input | lower }}dsrj01_prefix_lists.yml"
    name: prefix01
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: market_input | lower not in ["target1", "target2"]
```

Now, when `market_input=target1`, the second task `include dsrj01 variables...` task will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
  when: '"target1" not in market_input or "target2" not in market_input'
```

The second part of this condition is true (`"target2" not in "target1"`), so the task runs. You want to skip the task when either part is false, so you should be using `and`, not `or`.

```
  when: '"target1" not in market_input and "target2" not in market_input'
```